# Disable back button history on chrome didn't work

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I want to disable certain page in my apps website for security purpose by using this javascript code which is work fine in other browser:

```
history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
window.onpopstate = function () {
    history.go(1);
};
```

but unfortunately in chrome browser, this code is not activate unless user click on page or in developer tools of console, if you run any javascript there, for example like this:

```
console.log('test');
```

automatically the back button chrome browser is activated. I found out this issues already been discussed long time ago from this page:
[Google Chrome Help](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/8721521?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there as I came across this question quite a lot I posted my solution to this problem on the newest one asked but also wanted it to share here if its not to late.

[Heres the link to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59388091/12472435) hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
(function (global) {

if(typeof (global) === "undefined") {
  throw new Error("window is undefined");
}

var _hash = "!";
var noBackPlease = function () {
 global.location.href += "#";
 global.setTimeout(function () {
   global.location.href += "!";
 }, 50);
};

global.onhashchange = function () {
 if (global.location.hash !== _hash) {
   global.location.hash = _hash;
 }
};

global.onload = function () {
 noBackPlease();

// disables backspace on page except on input fields and textarea..
document.body.onkeydown = function (e) {
 var elm = e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase();
  if (e.which === 8 && (elm !== 'input' && elm  !== 'textarea')) {
     e.preventDefault();
  }
  // stopping event bubbling up the DOM tree..
  e.stopPropagation();
 };
}

})(window);

history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event)
{
history.pushState(null, document.title, location.href);
});

window.location.hash="no-back-button";
window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button";//again because google chrome don't insert first hash into history
window.onhashchange=function(){window.location.hash="no-back-button";}
```

Comment: I tested it just now, unfortunately it didnt work on chrome browser but it work fine in other browser like firefox. I manage to activate this function by clicking it one time inside the page. Here the example of above source code implementation:

[Codepen io](https://codepen.io/Azrulc/pen/WNNPmvg)

You can try it in chrome browser to see how it work.